# Do I need to get all 20 trinkets to get the hell out of the VVVVVV dimension?

Tags: vvvvvv

All members are rescued, the ship's been fixed, the dimension is collapsing, the entire map has been explored. However, the crew insists we "agreed" on finishing exploring the place. "Who knows what we'll find?"

Does the crew need all 20 trinkets to be convinced we've seen all there is to see of this collapsing time-space discontinuum, so we can move along and do whatever it is we were doing?

I do have 15/20 trinkets, but yes, the five missing trinkets are [all the hard ones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veO5D.png).

Comment: Related [to this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5015/what-happens-when-i-collect-the-shiny-circles-in-vvvvvv)? I haven't played the game, so I don't know if the Shiny Trinkets are different than the trinkets you're talking about.

Comment: @Grace It's related, but that question is limited to the achievement consequences of getting all trinkets, while my question focuses on the plot side.

Comment: "Unlock more of the story" is one of Kaestur's questions on it, so I wouldn't say the question is limited to achievements. If there's no *answers* addressing the story, that then seems to imply there is no effect on the story.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As someone who has managed to get all shiny trinkets, I can safely say you do need *all* of them to "finish" the game. The plot of the game is that, even though you've rescued your crew, and can ostensibly leave the collapsing dimension at any time, their home dimension is still in danger of collapsing like the one they were originally stranded in.

Without the shiny trinkets, your brave explorers can't guarantee a future for their dimension. In short, if you leave without all the shiny trinkets, it was [all for nothing](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AllForNothing).

So chin up, face those 5 last trinkets like a gamer, and know that everyone I've spoken to has died the most on "Veni", "Vedi", or "Vinci" (the game keeps track!).

On the plus side, unlike super meat boy bandages, once you've got the shiny trinket you're free to suicide to get back where you were.

Comment: I know the game keeps track, I've "finished" the game already. (They have to defeat The Final Challenge with 247 deaths... I hope they won't win.)

Comment: At any rate I'm now at 17/20. The tower one was wasn't hard after all, and I approached the LIES one the wrong way.